# Creating WAV chunks

Tags: c++, audio, wav

I'm trying to add custom chunks to existing WAV file. I'm using the mmioCreateChunk function but after it's execution nothing changes to the file. Here's the code of my program:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <mmsystem.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment( lib, "winmm" )

int main() 
{
  HMMIO       hmmio;                 // file handle for open file 
  MMCKINFO    mmckinfoParent;        // parent chunk information 
  MMCKINFO    mmckinfoFormatChunk;   // Format chunk information structure 
  MMCKINFO    mmckinfoDataChunk;     // Data chunk information structure
  MMCKINFO    mmckinfoRdibChunk;     // Rdib chunk information structure

  // Open the file for reading with buffered I/O 
  // by using the default internal buffer   
  if(!(hmmio = mmioOpen(L"out.wav", NULL, 
    MMIO_READ))) 
  { 
    cout << "Error opening file." << endl;
    return 0; 
  }

  // Locate a "RIFF" chunk with a "WAVE" form type to make 
  // sure the file is a waveform-audio file. 
  mmckinfoParent.fccType = mmioFOURCC('W', 'A', 'V', 'E'); 
  if (mmioDescend(hmmio, (LPMMCKINFO) &mmckinfoParent, NULL, 
    MMIO_FINDRIFF)) 
  { 
    cout << "This is not a waveform-audio file." << endl; 
    mmioClose(hmmio, 0); 
    return 0; 
  }

  // Find the "FMT" chunk (form type "FMT"); it must be 
  // a subchunk of the "RIFF" chunk. 
  mmckinfoFormatChunk.ckid = mmioFOURCC('f', 'm', 't', ' '); 
  if (mmioDescend(hmmio, &mmckinfoFormatChunk, &mmckinfoParent, 
    MMIO_FINDCHUNK)) 
  { 
    cout << "Waveform-audio file has no \"FMT\" chunk." << endl; 
    mmioClose(hmmio, 0); 
    return 0; 
  }

  unsigned int fmtSize = mmckinfoFormatChunk.cksize;
  char * waveFmt = new char[fmtSize];
  mmioRead(hmmio, waveFmt, mmckinfoFormatChunk.cksize);

  mmioAscend(hmmio, &mmckinfoFormatChunk, 0); 

  // Find the data subchunk. The current file position should be at 
  // the beginning of the data chunk; however, you should not make 
  // this assumption. Use mmioDescend to locate the data chunk. 
  mmckinfoDataChunk.ckid = mmioFOURCC('d', 'a', 't', 'a'); 
  if (mmioDescend(hmmio, &mmckinfoDataChunk, &mmckinfoParent, 
    MMIO_FINDCHUNK)) 
  { 
    cout << "Waveform-audio file has no data chunk." << endl; 
    mmioClose(hmmio, 0); 
    return 0;
  }

  unsigned int size = mmckinfoDataChunk.cksize;
  char* data = new char[size];
  mmioRead(hmmio, data, size);
  mmioClose(hmmio, 0);

  ifstream fs;
  fs.open("out.txt");

  // get length of file:
  fs.seekg (0, ios::end);
  int length = fs.tellg();
  fs.seekg (0, ios::beg);

  // allocate memory:
  char* buffer = new char [length];

  // read data as a block:
  fs.read (buffer,length);
  fs.close();

  HMMIO hmmio_out;

  //Creating new wav file.
  hmmio_out = mmioOpen(L"test.wav", 0, MMIO_CREATE | MMIO_WRITE);

  //Creating RIFF chunk
  mmioCreateChunk(hmmio_out, &mmckinfoParent, MMIO_CREATERIFF);

  //Creating format chunk and inserting information from source file
  mmioCreateChunk(hmmio_out, &mmckinfoFormatChunk, 0);
  mmioWrite(hmmio_out, waveFmt, mmckinfoFormatChunk.cksize);

  mmioAscend(hmmio_out, &mmckinfoFormatChunk, 0);

  //Creating data chunk and inserting information from source file
  mmioCreateChunk(hmmio_out, &mmckinfoDataChunk, 0);
  mmioWrite(hmmio_out, data, mmckinfoDataChunk.cksize);

  mmioAscend(hmmio_out, &mmckinfoDataChunk, 0);

  //Creating new rdib chunk and inserting information from out.txt
  mmckinfoRdibChunk.ckid = mmioFOURCC('r', 'd', 'i', 'b');
  mmckinfoRdibChunk.cksize = sizeof(char) * length;
  mmioCreateChunk(hmmio_out, &mmckinfoRdibChunk, 0);

  mmioWrite(hmmio_out, buffer, sizeof(char) * length);

  mmioAscend(hmmio_out, &mmckinfoRdibChunk, 0);

  // Close the file. 
  mmioClose(hmmio_out, 0); 

  return 0; 
}
```

What I have to do to create new chunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmioDescend begins searching at the current file position. So it will not find the chunk you have just written. You should first reset the file position to the start, or to a previous chunk.
Did you set the other chunk fields (ckSize and fccType) correctly? 
Perhaps you should perform an mmioAscend after creating the chunk to get the padding right.

Comment: I'm using the RIFF view app to see the riff file structure and it doesn't find new chunk to. But if I'm opening my file in notepad++ I can see the information inserted to it. That is my problem. The new code you can see in the edited topic main message.

Comment: You're setting the chunk length to the file length? The chunk may not be complete (it must have an even number of bytes), and that may be why RIFF view doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

See [Inside the RIFF Specification](http://drdobbs.com/database/184409308):

> If successful, **mmioCreateChunk() moves the current file position to
>   the beginning of the data area of the new chunk** (and after the chunk
>   type for RIFF or LIST chunks). **The contents of the chunk may then be
>   written using mmioWrite(), or** a subchunk may be created with another
>   call to mmioCreateChunk(). Note that mmioCreateChunk() cannot insert a
>   chunk partway into an already existing file. If this is attempted,
>   existing data in the file will be overwritten.

Comment: I also tried to create a new file and copy data from existing file to it but result was the same.

Comment: It adds information which I want to write to this file, but it doesn't recognizes it as a chunk.

Answer (score 0):

```
hmmio_out = mmioOpen(L"test.wav", 0, MMIO_CREATE | MMIO_WRITE);
```

should be

```
hmmio_out = mmioOpen(L"test.wav", 0, MMIO_CREATE | MMIO_READWRITE);
```

!attention it will erase contents of file due to MMIO_CREATE;